# Get a URL for a event in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

So I am looking for a way that once I find an event with the Elasticsearch API to return to the user a URL that they can use to access the event in the browser.

Is there a way to do it? Like I get back the event with the index, id and such from the _serach api, I want to return to my front end the data I find plus a link the user then can click to take them to the event in elastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

When you receive the response for Elasticsearch search you have the hits list. In each hit you have several "metadata" fields: _index, _id e.t.c.
You can combine the URI dor this fields like:

```
http://YOUR_DAOMAIN:PORT/<_index>/_doc/<_id 
Where:
_index - index name from the search responce 
_doc - doctype (in latest version deprecated, so this is "_doc" in all documents
_id - doc id from the search response
```

For example:
http://localhost:9200/metricbeat-7-2022.03.24/_doc/adfgafgasdgnlk